# Execute for loop iterations in openmp in order with dynamic schedule

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'd like to run a for loop in openmp with dynamic schedule.

```
#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,chunk) private(i) nowait
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
//loop code here
}
```

and I'd like to have each thread executing ordered chunks such that

e.g. thread 1 -> iterations 0 to k

thread2 -> iterations k+1->k+chunk

etc..

Static schedule partly does what I want but I'd like to dynamically load balance the iterations.

Neither ordered clause, if I understood correctly what it does.

My question is how to make sure that the chunks assigned are ordered chunks?

I am using openmp 3.1 with gcc

Comment: You might like a `guided` schedule.  As it stands you want to have your cake and eat it -- you want OpenMP to load balance for you but you also want it to assign chunks in order.  How can the scheduler know that, to take an extreme example, loop 1 doesn't take as long as loops 2 to 250 ?  Having given loop 1 to thread 1, what should the scheduler do with loop 2  and thread 2 ?

Comment: I don't get your question. How is `schedule(dynamic,chunk)` not what you want?

Comment: @HristoIliev I thought that dynamic schedule picks randomly unordered iterations. If chunk = 5 and N=10 and threads=2, can´t it be that thread 1 has e.g iterations {0,3,5,6,9} ? I´d like to avoid this situation.

Comment: You need to give more details of why you want to do this.  Let me give you an example where I did something some what like you describe. I was generating frames of an animation. I generated each frame in parallel. Let's say I had two threads. Let each iteration be a pixel.  On the first frame I let each frame process half the pixels. Then I determine how long each thread took. Let's say the first thread took twice as long. On the next frame I had thread1 do e.g 1/3 the pixels and thread2 2/3 pixels. This balanced the load better. In other words I dynamically adjusted the chunks between frames.

Comment: So if you had an outer loop that is not parallel and an inner loop you run in parallel then you could dynamics adjust the chunks for the inner loop based on the timing after each iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: `schedule(dynamic,chunk)` means that each thread receives a chunk of `chunk` iterations and does them in sequence, then asks for another one. If `N=10` and there are two threads, the only difference between `schedule(dynamic,5)` and `schedule(static)` is that in the latter case thread 0 is guaranteed to get the first chunk of 5 iterations while in the former case it could be either thread 0 or thread 1. The situation you are afraid of occurs when `chunk=1` as in `schedule(dynamic)`. Then each iteration could get scheduled to a random thread.

Comment: It is much clearer now. Thanks @HristoIliev. Apologies for confusing everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this yourself without resorting to `omp for`, which is considered a convenience function by expert OpenMP programmers.

The following roughly illustrates what you might do.  Please check the arithmetic carefully.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
  int me = omp_get_thread_num();
  int nt = omp_get_num_threads();
  int chunk = /* divide n by nt appropriately */
  int start = me * chunk;
  int end   = (me+1) * chunk;
  if (end > n) end = n;
  for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
      /* do work */
  }
} /* end parallel */
```

This does not do any dynamic load-balancing.  You can do that yourself by assigning loop iterations unevenly to threads if you know the cost function a priori.  You might read up on the inspector-executor model (e.g. [1](http://gac.des.udc.es/~juan/papers/ispa2004.pdf)).

Comment: This logic is something which I'm interested in , I have a an iteration of 1000000, imagine I have 8 parallel threads then for first 8 this logic fits? Once they finish task this logic does work because again  thread 0 or 1 come and need to pick next chuck of iteration and now thread id isn't 9 yo pick next iteration ! Please answer my question